# Secure web module for paid subscribtion

Tags: c#, .net, module, billing

I'm building a website (a community web site like digg) but we will soon release a new feature that people will need to pay for.

Right now, our website is in pure C# in .NET, very simple pages with some AJAX. When the member log in, there is no HTTPS. Everything is check with session and the internal validation that I do.

What we need, is that when the people are logged in, they can click on a link a proceed to a payment (Paypal, credit card, etc). After the payment is done, the "billing module" will return a value to my site to validate that the payment is done so the account will be flagged as "paying member". I'm guessing this is the way to do, maybe I'm wrong!

So my questions are: 
-What is the name of this kind of billing module? (I will do some research on that)
-Do you know any ready to go module that does this kind of thing?
-(I push my luck) Do you know any FREE module that do this kind of things.

If something is not clear, don't hesitate to ask question :)

********EDIT****************
Some people suggest me paypal IPN, is there anything else before I close this post?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @barrycarter: you mean https://www.paypal.com/ipn ?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I need, can you create a comment with this answer to I can credit you the good answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paypal IPN should do the job